Simple substitution with ExifTool
I manually rewrite a part of a jpg metadata using the next code in bash (linux):
date_field=`exiftool -FileModifyDate file.jpg`
raw_date=${date_field:34:19}
new_date=${raw_date/2024/2022}
exiftool -overwrite_original "-FileModifyDate=$new_date" file.jpg

That works by I would like to do this directly. I've tried
exiftool -overwrite_original '-FileModifyDate<${FileModifyDate/2024/2022}' file.jpg

but it does not work (It doesn't throw any error either).
How do I code that substitution correctly?

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag. Shellcheck would have identified the problem, explained it and provided the solution.

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

You don't have a variable named FileModifyDate. Shouldn't that be raw_date?
